# How to Disable Follow Feature on Django-Activity-Stream

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-activity-stream

I'm creating a Django application with [django-activity-stream](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream). I've registered the app inside the project. Unfortunately, the built-in follower/following feature of the app conflicts with my Follow table - I want more granular control than the library allows. Anyone know how to disable the feature or sidestep this issue?

```
ERRORS:
actstream.Follow.content_type: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Follow.content_type' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Follow.content_type'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Follow.content_type' or 'Follow.content_type'.
actstream.Follow.user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Follow.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Follow.user'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Follow.user' or 'Follow.user'.
content.Follow.content_type: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Follow.content_type' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Follow.content_type'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Follow.content_type' or 'Follow.content_type'.
content.Follow.user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Follow.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Follow.user'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Follow.user' or 'Follow.user'.
```

Follow Model:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a related_name to your model fields:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                     related_name='my_follow_user')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,  
                     on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                     related_name='my_follow_content_type')
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

or something similar.

Django Models ref:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/